# Is it possible to play animation around the real object when image anchor is detected in RealityKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, augmented-reality, realitykit

In RealityKit, I have an image anchor. When the image anchor is detected I would like to play some animation around the real object of that image on ARView. I don't want put any 3D object around it and play animation on that object. I can do that using the Reality Composer.

I want to play some animations on the anchor when image anchor is detected on ARView.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ARViewContainer().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
        
        let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)

        context.coordinator.view = arView
        context.coordinator.setupUI()
        
        return arView
        
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {}

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject {

    weak var view: ARView?
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    func setupUI() {
        guard let arView = self.view else { return }

        guard let imageAnchor = try? Experience.loadMasalaEarth() else {
            fatalError("Unable to load my image anchor scene")
        }

        // Here, I want to play animation on the actual object, when image anchor is detected.

        arView.scene.addAnchor(imageAnchor)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to play animation on real object or we can only play animation on the 3d object that we put on the detected anchors?

Comment: @AndyJazz, I want to play like animated border with some colors when detected the image anchor.

Comment: @AndyJazz, around the scaned object, which is image anchor or object anchor